# using format_datetime filter in twig

Tags: twig

I show on a page a list of dates in french format.

I want to show date in french like this : "Janvier 2022".
The date stored in database is "2022-01-01".

Twig code :

```
{{ someDate | format_datetime(locale='fr', pattern="MMMM Y") | capitalize }}
```

Problem : it's showing "Janvier 2021", not "2022".
But the next date is correct, "Février 2022".

I don't understand why the year is 2021 and not 2022.

Please help !!

Comment: Did you cross-check the values present in the database? Surprising that one value is right while the other isn't

Comment: Yes all values are ok. When I try  "locale='none'" the date is shown correctly but not in french...

Comment: Oh! Is it for all the dates in January or just the 1st day?

Comment: It's just for the first and second day... for other days it seems to work... good remark :)

Comment: This looks like a timezone issue. Is the date stored with TZ information? Is the server correctly setup?

Answer (score 0):

The week does not start the same day in France as in other countries
For year, use yyyy instead YYYY.

More information : [Date format return wrong year in PHP with DateFmt in French](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71394171/date-format-return-wrong-year-in-php-with-datefmt-in-french)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).