# Date format return wrong year in PHP with DateFmt in French

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

I wrote this function

```
function formatted_month($month) {
    $first_day_in_month = new DateTime('2022-01-01');

    $fmt = datefmt_create(
        'en_EN',
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        'Europe/Paris',
        IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
        'MMMM YY'
    );
    $formatted_month = datefmt_format($fmt,$first_day_in_month);

    return $formatted_month;
}
```

This return January 22 as expected but this code :

```
function formatted_month($month) {
    $first_day_in_month = new DateTime('2022-01-01');

    $fmt = datefmt_create(
        'fr_FR',
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        'Europe/Paris',
        IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
        'MMMM YY'
    );
    $formatted_month = datefmt_format($fmt,$first_day_in_month);

    return $formatted_month;
}
```

Return janvier 21. The only difference is this line

```
'en_EN', -> 'fr_FR'
```

Same thing for es_ES and non English languages...

Do you have any explanation ?
Thanks

Comment: https://3v4l.org/9sITi if anyone wants a live playground

Comment: It probably has to do with how each of those locales defines the first week of the year? https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=en&_=fr_FR: `First day of the week: 2 ( 1=SUNDAY ); Minimal Days in First Week: 4`, https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=en&_=en_en: `First day of the week: 2 ( 1=SUNDAY ); Minimal Days in First Week: 1` Starting from `2022-01-03`, I get the same year reported with both locales.

Comment: As an aside, "en_EN" is technically invalid as a locale identifier - the second component should be a country code, and there is no country with code "EN"; it should be "en_GB", "en_US", "en_CA", etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is a subtle mistake of the formatting string, which is that there are multiple different year specifiers:

- A *lower-case* `yy` or `yyyy` is the normal year you would expect, for use with month and day
- An *upper-case* `YY` or `YYYY` is the year for use with "week of year"

For the majority of dates, these are the same, so the difference is easy to overlook. But at the very beginning and end of the year, it matters where the week begins and ends - January 1st may still be in the last week of the previous year, or December 31st may be in the first week of the next year.

We can see the difference clearly if we use a format string of `'ww YYYY, MMMM yyyy'`, to show the week number and both definitions of year:

- For `en_GB` we get "01 2022, January 2022"
- For `fr_FR` we get "52 2021, janvier 2022"

So always use the lower-case "yy" form, unless you are actually displaying week numbers.

```
function formatted_month($month) {
    $first_day_in_month = new DateTime('2022-01-01');

    $fmt = datefmt_create(
        'fr_FR',
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        'Europe/Paris',
        IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
        'MMMM yy'
    );

    $formatted_month = datefmt_format($fmt,$first_day_in_month);

    return $formatted_month;
}
```